# Jenkins input step do something after reach waiting threshold limit

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a stage in my pipeline job that requires user input to proceed to the next stage. The problem is sometime I forget to click the proceed button after N minutes of waiting. I want to send a Slack message to notify me that the stage has been paused for N minutes. Is there a way to achieve it?

Below is the sample of my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting Stage A'
                input message: 'Continue to the next stage?'
                // send Slack message after 15 minutes user didn't click Proceed/Abort button
                // but still wait for user input (don't mark it as failed even after 15 minutes)
            }
        }

        stage('B') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting Stage B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using Jenkins timeout feature using the pipeline script below

But, if the timeout is reached, it will continue to the next stage automatically. What I want is even after the timeout is reached, still wait for user input on Stage A (don't continue to the Stage B immediately)

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        echo 'Starting Stage A'
                        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                            input message: 'Continue to the next stage?'
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
                        if ('SYSTEM' == user.toString()) { // failed because of timeout
                            // send Slack message
                            // how to still wait for user input on this stage even after timeout is reached?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('B') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting Stage B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the script below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Starting Stage A'

                    def showInputAgain = false
                    def proceed = true

                    try {
                        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                            input message: 'Continue?'
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
                        if ('SYSTEM' == user.toString()) {
                            showInputAgain = true
                            echo 'Stage A failed. Reach timeout. Sending message to Slack'
                        } else {
                            proceed = false
                            echo 'Stage A failed. User abort'
                        }
                    }

                    if (proceed && showInputAgain) {
                        input message: 'Continue?'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('B') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting Stage B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But any other inputs/answers will be appreciated